# Error when runing query from form between two date from a form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have a form called FirstInLastOut which looks as the image below.[image: Form]

Based on Name or badge number I want to search between two dates.

I am using the following criteria on the query:

`>=[Forms]![FirstInLastOut]![StartDateEntry] And <=[Forms]![FirstInLastOut]![EndDateEntry]`

This is given me results that include other months as well. Please see the query report below.

[image: FirstinlastoutReport]

So as you can see in the image the numbers of the dates are falling with the the parameter but getting other months as well.

How can I make it so it will only select the dates between the date ranges?

```sql
SELECT FistClockInRaw.Badgenumber, FistClockInRaw.name, FistClockInRaw.lastname, FistClockInRaw.MinOfCHECKTIME, FLastClockOutRaw.MaxOfCHECKTIME, [MaxOfCHECKTIME]-[MinOfCHECKTIME] AS TotalHours, FLastClockOutRaw.QDate, FistClockInRaw.MinOfQTime, FLastClockOutRaw.MaxOfQTime, RawCompleteQuery.CHECKTIME
FROM RawCompleteQuery, FLastClockOutRaw INNER JOIN FistClockInRaw ON (FLastClockOutRaw.Badgenumber = FistClockInRaw.Badgenumber) AND (FLastClockOutRaw.name = FistClockInRaw.name) AND (FLastClockOutRaw.QDate = FistClockInRaw.QDate)
WHERE (((FistClockInRaw.name)=[Forms]![FirstInLastOut]![FirstNameEntry]) AND ((RawCompleteQuery.CHECKTIME)>=[Forms]![FirstInLastOut]![StartDateEntry] And (RawCompleteQuery.CHECKTIME)<=[Forms]![FirstInLastOut]![EndDateEntry]));
```

is the Query

Comment: It compares the entered dates as text, not dates, so it will select all dates with days between 15 and 19. So, for correct results the data type in table/query should be date and convert the text on the selection form to date data type first

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the forms fields `StartDateEntry` and `EndDateEntry` are bound to fields of type `date`.

I also assume that you are only interested to compare the date part of those form fields.

So try this condition instead to assure correct date interpreting:

```sql
WHERE FistClockInRaw.name=[Forms]![FirstInLastOut]![FirstNameEntry]
AND RawCompleteQuery.CHECKTIME >= Format([Forms]![FirstInLastOut]![StartDateEntry], "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#")
AND RawCompleteQuery.CHECKTIME <= Format([Forms]![FirstInLastOut]![EndDateEntry], "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#")
```

**A remark:**

Be aware that every date field/variable always contains a time part too!

So your current logic comparing `EndDateEntry` with `<=` can cause trouble, because you would only get results of the end date having time values of `00:00:00` in the field `CHECKTIME`.

If any record of `CHECKTIME` contains the requested end date and a time part bigger then `00:00:00`, it is not in the result.

To avoid that, you should use `<` and add one day:

```sql
And RawCompleteQuery.CHECKTIME < Format([Forms]![FirstInLastOut]![EndDateEntry] + 1, "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#")
```